# Generic Factory method to instantiate a derived class from the base class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, factory-pattern

I am in the process of creating a factory method which uses a generic abstract type parameter to return the instance of the concrete derived type using reflection. For eg.

```
public abstract class ServiceClientBase : IServiceClient
{
}

public abstract class Channel : ServiceClientBase
{
}

public class ChannelImpl : Channel
{
}

public class ServiceClientFactory
{
    public T GetService<T>() where T : class, IServiceClient
    {
        // Use reflection to create the derived type instance
        T instance = typeof(T).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null).Invoke(new object[] { endPointUrl }) as T;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Channel channelService = factory.GetService<Channel>();
```

The issue is that I cannot figure out any elegant way for the factory method to instantiate the derived type being passed the abstract base type in the method. The only thing I can come up with is to maintain a Dictionary containing the map between the abstract base and the corresponding derived class but this seems to me like a code smell. Can anybody suggest a better solution.

Comment: Well, suppose you had two different concrete implementations of the abstract class - how would you want to make the decision then?

Comment: That is exactly my concern. Just that in my particular case, I know that there will only be one specific implementation. But still, I was looking for a more elegant way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to create a WCF proxy? I would be interested in the full context because you may be trying to recreate the wheel.

Comment: @Bronumski No, I am not trying to create a WCF proxy ... the channel class name might be misleading. I am just trying to create a way for the clients using the API to be able to create an instance of the concrete class by using a generic type parameter of the abstract base type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you're confident of there being only one implementation, and assuming it's within the same assembly, you could find it via reflection. For example:

```
Type implementationType = typeof(T).Assembly.GetTypes()
                                   .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))
                                   .Single();
return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(implementationType);
```

Of course for performance reasons you may well want to have a cache of abstract type to concrete type.

If there are multiple implementation classes, you'll need to think of an alternative - one option would be an attribute on the abstract class saying which implementation to use, if that's feasible. (It's hard to give good options without more context.)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attempting to reinvent an IOC container.  Take a look at [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) for example.  You would register your concrete types with the IOC container and then request them by interface.

Comment: That actually might be a worthwhile option to look at. I was just working on a POC. So, I was trying to figure out a easy to work alternative. I would definitely consider using IOC to resolve the dependency.